# How apply pagination in reactive Spring Data?

Tags: spring-data, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

In Spring Data, we have `PagingAndSortingRepository` which inherits from `CrudRepository`. In reactive Spring Data, we only have 
`ReactiveSortingRepository` which inherits from `ReactiveCrudRepository`.
How could we make pagination in a reactive way ?
Will we able to make this in future with `ReactivePagingAndSortingRepository` for instance?

Comment: What is the use case you want to address? Is it bulk data processing (page-by-page) or do you want to just fetch a particular chunk of data?

Comment: second point. I just want to mage a webservice by paginating data and not retrieving all in one shot

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reactive Spring Data MongoDB repositories do not provide paging in the sense of paging how it's designed for imperative repositories. Imperative paging requires additional details while fetching a page. In particular:

- The number of returned records for a paging query
- Optionally, total count of records the query yields if the number of returned records is zero or matches the page size to calculate the overall number of pages

Both aspects do not fit to the notion of efficient, non-blocking resource usage. Waiting until all records are received (to determine the first chunk of paging details) would remove a huge part of the benefits you get by reactive data access. Additionally, executing a count query is rather expensive, and increases the lag until you're able to process data.

You can still fetch chunks of data yourself by passing a `Pageable` (`PageRequest`) to repository query methods:

```
interface ReactivePersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  Flux<Person> findByFirstnameOrderByLastname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Spring Data will apply pagination to the query by translating `Pageable` to `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

References:

- [Reference documentation: Reactive repository usage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.0.RC3/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories.usage)

Comment: How can the left pages be retrived with your example? In non-reactive style the repositories are providing the type Page<Person> which contains the information. In your example with Flux the Page informations are not available.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478189/how-can-i-return-a-fluxorder-when-my-response-is-wrapped-in-a-json-pagination

Comment: You'd need to get the count and calculate the remaining pages from there on.

Comment: Any plan to provide that functionality into the framework? Support for Cursor based pagination would be awesome.

Comment: Synchronizing on results and adding a count removes a lot of the benefits that reactive gives you. Not quite sure whether framework-level support would make sense for the broad audience.

Comment: And it seems Spring Data does not provide a reactive  `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve `Pageable` in controller.

Comment: @mp911de But when I wrote tests for the pagination, I am not sure why the [test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/data-mongo-pageable/src/test/java/com/example/demo/ApplicationTests.java#L52-L75) of `countByTitleLike` failed in a mock env.

Comment: I disagree with your argument, returning a page of objects from a rest endpoint is quite a common requirement, even if it has to do a 100 database requests, as long as it is in a non-blocking fashion right?

Answer (score 10):

```
import com.thepracticaldeveloper.reactiveweb.domain.Quote;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public interface QuoteMongoReactiveRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Quote, String> {

    @Query("{ id: { $exists: true }}")
    Flux<Quote> retrieveAllQuotesPaged(final Pageable page);
}
```

more details , [you could check here](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/11/04/full-reactive-stack-with-spring-webflux-and-angularjs/)

Comment: +1 Your solution works like a charm!!! I have changed naming using findAll  @Query("{ id: { \$exists: true }}")
    fun findAll(page: Pageable): Flux< Quote >

Answer (score 1):

I created a service with this method for anyone that may still be looking for a solution:

```
@Resource
private UserRepository userRepository; //Extends ReactiveSortingRepository<User, String>

public Mono<Page<User>> findAllUsersPaged(Pageable pageable) {
        return this.userRepository.count()
                .flatMap(userCount -> {
                    return this.userRepository.findAll(pageable.getSort())
                            .buffer(pageable.getPageSize(),(pageable.getPageNumber() + 1))
                            .elementAt(pageable.getPageNumber(), new ArrayList<>())
                            .map(users -> new PageImpl<User>(users, pageable, userCount));
                });
    }
```

Comment: Won't it find all documents in DB side?

Answer (score 0):

I have created another approach using @kn3l solution (without using @Query ):

```
fun findByIdNotNull(page: Pageable): Flux< Quote>
```

It creates the same query without using @Query method

Answer (score 0):

```
public Mono<Page<ChatUser>> findByChannelIdPageable(String channelId, Integer page, Integer size) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "chatChannels.joinedTime"));
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria("chatChannels.chatChannelId").is(channelId);
    Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    Flux<ChatUser> chatUserFlux = reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, ChatUser.class, "chatUser");
    Mono<Long> countMono = reactiveMongoTemplate.count(Query.of(query).limit(-1).skip(-1), ChatUser.class);
    return Mono.zip(chatUserFlux.collectList(),countMono).map(tuple2 -> {
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
                tuple2.getT1(),
                pageable,
                () -> tuple2.getT2());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Please add some explaining text describing the idea behind your solution.

Comment: Code-only answers are low qualty answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and end up having similar approach as the above but changed slightly the code as I use Query DSL, following example if someone needed.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String>, ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

    default Flux<Person> applyPagination(Flux<Person> persons, Pageable pageable) {
    return persons.buffer(pageable.getPageSize(), (pageable.getPageNumber() + 1))
        .elementAt(pageable.getPageNumber(), new ArrayList<>())
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    }

}


public Flux<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable, Predicate predicate) {
    return personRepository.applyPagination(personRepository.findAll(predicate), pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for some idea for reactive pageable repositories I had seen solutions that will result in horrible boiler plate code so I ended up with this (did not tried yet in real life but should work fine, or maybe it can be inspiration for your solution)

So … let's create a brand new toolbox class with such method

```
    public static 
           <R extends PageableForReactiveMongo<S, K>, S, T, K> Mono<Page<T>>
           pageableForReactiveMongo(Pageable pageable, 
                                             R repository, Class<T> clazzTo) {
        return repository.count()
                .flatMap(c ->
                        repository.findOderByLimitedTo(pageable.getSort(),
                                              pageable.getPageNumber() + 1)
                                .buffer(pageable.getPageSize(), (pageable.getPageNumber() + 1))
                                .elementAt(pageable.getPageNumber(), new ArrayList<>())
                                .map(r -> mapToPage(pageable, c, r, clazzTo))
                );
    }
```

and it will need also something like that:

```
    private static <S, T> Page<T> mapToPage(Pageable pageable, Long userCount, Collection<S> collection, Class<T> clazzTo) {
        return new PageImpl<>(
                collection.stream()
                        .map(r -> mapper.map(r, clazzTo))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                , pageable, userCount);
    }
```

and then we need also an abstract layer wrapping reactive repositories

```
public interface PageableForReactiveMongo<D, K> extends ReactiveMongoRepository<D, K> {
    Flux<D> findOderByLimitedTo(Sort sort, int i);
}
```

to let it instantiate by spring

```
@Repository
interface ControllerRepository extends PageableForReactiveMongo<ControllerDocument, String> {
}
```

And finally use it many many many times like that

```
public Mono<Page<Controller>> findAllControllers(Pageable pageable) {
    return getFromPageableForReactiveMongo(pageable, controllerRepository, Controller.class);
}
```

this is how your code can look like :) please tell me if it is fine, or helped out with something