# ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository not allowing Pageable parameter in find query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, reactive-programming, project-reactor

ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository in spring data for couchbase reactive not allowing `Pageable` parameter in `find` query

I have pojo called `MyEntity` as shown below. 
When I run the second find query below without `Pageable`, it returns correctly with response, but when I run with `Pageable` parameter , then it throws below exception while initializing the application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page, interface java.util.List, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice]
```

Though it should work as shown in the reference documentation as well as here for MongoDb

[how-apply-pagination-in-reactive-spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391830/5105808)

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Instant effectiveDateTime;
    private String createdBy;
    private Instant createdDateTime;
}

public interface EntityRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {

Flux<MyEntity> findByEffectiveDateTimeBetween(Instant start, Instant end, Pageable pageable) ;
Flux<MyEntity> findByEffectiveDateTimeBetween(Instant start, Instant end) ;
}





Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page, interface java.util.List, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]

caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to have one of the following return types! [interface org.springframework.data.domain.Page, interface java.util.List, interface org.springframework.data.domain.Slice]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.assertReturnTypeAssignable(QueryMethod.java:301) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.CouchbaseQueryMethod.<init>(CouchbaseQueryMethod.java:47) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ReactiveCouchbaseRepositoryFactory$CouchbaseQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(ReactiveCouchbaseRepositoryFactory.java:222) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
```

On further reading, it seems like a bug in spring data commons library.
because the class `QueryExecutionConverters.java` in spring data from where it is checking the return type doesn't contain `Flux` or any reactive type in its list.

Can somebody confirm whether its documentation error or code error in spring data commons.

```
ALLOWED_PAGEABLE_TYPES.add(Slice.class);
ALLOWED_PAGEABLE_TYPES.add(Page.class);
ALLOWED_PAGEABLE_TYPES.add(List.class);
```