# Pagination for a findAll method in Spring Data Mongodb Reactive repositories

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

There's already a [question about pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384618/how-apply-pagination-in-reactive-spring-data) with `ReactiveCrudRepository`. The accepted solution works for queries following a `findBy` format. The project documentation also references that usage:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories.usage

> Example 158. Basic repository interface to persist Person entities
>
> ```
> public interface ReactivePersonRepository extends
> ReactiveSortingRepository<Person, String> {
>
>   Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);                     
>
>
>   Flux<Person> findByFirstname(Publisher<String> firstname);          
>
>
>   Flux<Person> findByFirstnameOrderByLastname(String firstname,
> Pageable pageable); 
>
>   Mono<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String
> lastname);       
>
>   Mono<Person> findFirstByLastname(String lastname);                  
> }
> ```

The problem is this doesn't work for findAll:

```
interface CustomerRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Customer, String> {
    fun findAll(pageable: Pageable): Flux<Customer>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Customer!
```

Does Spring Data MongoDB support this in some way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `findAll(Pageable pageable)` is a method of `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Spring data support method query using `findBy` which is not related with `findAll(Pageable pageable)`.

Currently Reactive Spring Data MongoDB don't support any mehtod like `findAll(pageable: Pageable)` but there is a way to do it.

```
interface CustomerRepository : ReactiveSortingRepository<Customer, String> {
    fun findByIdNotNull(pageable: Pageable): Flux<Customer>
}
```

You can read more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384618/how-apply-pagination-in-reactive-spring-data)

Comment: take care that it not work with something like `findAllPaged`. it works with `findByIdNotNull` as in the example.

Comment: @Eklavya did anything changed with it?